# multi select checkbox value in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

```
<div *ngFor="let user_id of filterdUsers; let i = index"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="something{{i}}" class="something{{i}}"  [checked]= "something === model.user_id"  [(ngModel)]="model.user_id" [value] = "user_id._id" (click)="onCheckClick($event, user_id)"> {{user_id.username}} 
</div>
```

I am generating the checkboxes at run time. when I am clicking the checkbox all the checkboxes are selected and getting the multiple checkboxes values on clicking on single checkbox. In above code filterdUsers is an ARRAY OF OBJECT

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you. Maybe a https://stackblitz.com demo?

Comment: What is the structure of object `something`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue that could be solved by `trackBy`

```
<div *ngFor="let user_id of filterdUsers; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn"> 
   <input type="checkbox" name="something{{i}}" class="something{{i}}"  [checked]= "something === model.user_id"  [(ngModel)]="model.user_id" [value] = "user_id._id" (click)="onCheckClick($event, user_id)"> {{user_id.username}} 
</div>
```

Then add the function to your component:

```
trackByFn(i: number) {
    return i;
  }
```

This allows angular to intelligently index the `ngFor` and assign values correctly.